# C# using expressions in RDLC report

Tags: c#, expression, rdlc

I am having trouble generating the RDL report in C# project. If I don't use expressions, the report generates correctly. When I set an expression for the background color:

```
=IIf(Fields!dzien.Value="Sunday","LightGrey","Transparent")
```

generating the report ends with an error.

[image: screenshot raport error]

In project I have references

[image: screenshot project]

What am I doing wrong? Compilation proceeds without errors.

Comment: Fields!dzien.Value=="Sunday" ?

Comment: this syntax does not compile

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully resolved the problem. Microsoft Report Viewer 2015 Runtime was missing from the operating system.